# How to get host URL in the background service in asp .net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having an Asp .Net core web api which will run a background service to schedule some task daily and will send some mail. In the mail I need to have the url of the api. Is there any way to get the host URL in the background services other than controllers.

Comment: Why do you need that URL? The background service itself doesn't need that ULR to call the Web API service, it *is* part of the service. You can't use the service's URL in an email either, as it's almost certainly *not* same as the public URL exposed by the firewall, load balancers or IIS. There may be many different host names/URLs configured for the same service too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want the URL hosted by the web api where the background service is running

Answer (score 7):

Background services run outside the scope of a web request, hence *background* service. This means that there is no HTTP context available where you can grab the host of the application from. I suggest you create an application setting where you configure the host for the current environment, e.g. `appsettings.Staging.json`, `appsettings.Production.json`, etc and use that in your background service by injecting `IConfiguration` or a specific options class.